# Haproxy rate limits by URL parameter

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy, rate-limiting

We have a haproxy and need to rate limit per second requests to API by URL parameter(token\key).
Right now we have test a configuration from documentation:

```
frontend website
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/crt.pem

    stick-table type string size 100k expire 1s store http_req_rate(1s)

    acl exceeds_limit_key url_param(key),table_http_req_rate() gt 1000
    acl exceeds_limit url_param(token),table_http_req_rate() gt 1000

    http-request track-sc0 url_param(key) unless exceeds_limit_key
    http-request track-sc0 url_param(token) unless exceeds_limit

    http-request deny deny_status 429 if exceeds_limit_key or exceeds_limit
    default_backend servers
```

But we need to change the limit for each token, at the moment we are trying to use `rates.map` with this config:

```
frontend website
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/crt.pem

    stick-table type string size 100k expire 1s store http_req_rate(1s)

    http-request track-sc0 base32+src

    http-request set-var(req.rate_limit)  url_param,map_beg(/etc/haproxy/rates.map,500)

    http-request set-var(req.request_rate)  base32+src,table_http_req_rate()

    acl rate_abuse var(req.rate_limit),sub(req.request_rate) lt 0  
    
    http-request deny deny_status 429 if rate_abuse
    
    default_backend servers
```

And rates.map:

```
#token
DB6sa5rdASVDGhasd67rdasd        100
```

But with this configuration we have always default limits `url_param,map_beg(/etc/haproxy/rates.map,500)`.
For my opinion problem in `rates.map` file. The question is, in what form should the `rates.map` file for `url_param` be?

Comment: Hey, were you able to resolve this? I am running into a similar problem. In my case, haproxy complains that the value read is not an integer. My config looks like this `http-request content set-var(req.temp_rate_limit) str(test),lower,map_beg(rate-limits.map,100)`